# performing many gradient-based optimizations in parallel with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I have a model which requires solving a system of ODEs with `tfp.math.ode.BDF`, and I would like to find the individual least-squares fits of this model to n > 1000 datasets. That is to say, if my model has m parameters then at the end of the optimization process I will have an n by m tensor of best-fit parameter values.

What would be the best way to perform this optimization in parallel? At this point I’m planning to define an objective function that adds up the n individual sums of square residuals, and then uses `tfp.optimizer.lbfgs_minimize` to find the best-fit values of the combined n×m parameters.

Comment: D you want each of the n sets of weights to be optimal for its individual dataset? I assume yes?

Comment: @Yaoshiang Yes, each of the n sets of weights should result in a global minimum of the n corresponding model-fitting objective functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't be super helpful, and I don't know what ODEs are, but if I were attempting to optimizing in parallel ANY set of n datasets against n models (be it linear regression or deep learning or any other model that's optimized via gradients), I'd simply instantiate n copies of the model, forward prop all n datasets against a corresponding model, and critically, sum up the loss. Automatic differentiation will take care of the rest.

The n models do not interact with each other, other than the final summation of loss, so auto diff will keep the gradients isolated as well. I haven't used l-bfgs in a while but IIRC it's like SGD except it factors in the second order partial derivative, so it's probably implemented with a gradient tape inside a gradient tape.

Here is a minimal example of constructing a single tensorflow model that contains n=2 models. Each model contains m=2 weights (namely, m and b from the y=mx+b equation). You train on n datasets which have a 1-to-1 relationship with the n models. You will get n by m weights out of it.

```
import tensorflow as tf


def get_model():
  """Create linear regression model of the form y=mx+b."""
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,)))
  return model

# Setup two different datasets. 
x1 = tf.range(start=-1., limit=1., delta=0.001)
y1 = x1 * .1 + .2

x2 = tf.range(start=-1., limit=1., delta=0.001)
y2 = x2 * .3 + .4


def create_parallel_model():
  """Creates a single model that hold multiple independent models.
  
  Returns:
    parallel_model: The single parallel model holding multiple models. 
    model1: First componenent model. 
    model2: Second componenent model. 
    """
  model1 = get_model()
  model2 = get_model()

  inp1 = tf.keras.Input((1,), name='inp1')
  inp2 = tf.keras.Input((1,), name='inp2')

  outp1 = model1(inp1)
  outp2 = model2(inp2)

  parallel_model = tf.keras.Model([inp1, inp2], [outp1, outp2])

  return parallel_model, model1, model2


pmodel, model1, model2 = create_parallel_model()
pmodel.compile('sgd', 'mse')
pmodel.fit(x=[x1, x2], y=[y1, y2], epochs=100)

print("First model's dense layer, m and b should be 0.1 and 0.2.")
print(model1.layers[0].get_weights())

print("Second model's dense layer, m and b should be 0.3 and 0.4.")
print(model2.layers[0].get_weights())
```

Your output should look like

```
First model's dense layer, m and b should be 0.1 and 0.2.
[array([[0.10000037]], dtype=float32), array([0.20000002], dtype=float32)]
Second model's dense layer, m and b should be 0.3 and 0.4.
[array([[0.30000147]], dtype=float32), array([0.39999998], dtype=float32)]
```

Another way to do this is to simply train one model and dataset at a time within a single process, but run multiple processes in parallel. If you use TF's dynamic memory allocation, TF won't hog up all the GPU ram and Nvidia GPU's do support multi-processing
(https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/mps/index.html).

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') 
for gpu_instance in physical_devices: 
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu_instance, True)
```

Comment: Would you use `tf.map_fn` to run the optimizations in parallel?

Comment: ODE = ordinary differential equation

Comment: I would not use tf.map_fn... I've updated my answer with the ultra simple example of SGD on a linear regression.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the BDF optimizer and LBFGS both support batches (of problems), so you *could* have an outer "problem" axis to your data and leastsq return value. But since BDF is for stiff problems, it's likely to have much longer runtimes for some problems than for others, and you might be best served treating each problem separately (tf.map_fn) as opposed to running them all in parallel -- in a batch, you can't run ahead onto the next LBFGS iteration for problem X until you compute the BDF integration for problem Y. Or just use a python for loop over your problems, each time calling a `@tf.function def lbfgs_over_bdf(data): ...`.

Comment: You make a good point. I'll do an initial test integration for each problem to sort out the problems with particularly stiff ODE systems. That should allow me to do the bulk of the optimization work in parallel on a GPU.

Comment: Could stiffness cause the autograd implementation to fail? If you had the time, I'd greatly appreciate your input on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69845226/avoiding-matrix-inversion-error-when-taking-gradient-of-tensorflow-numerical-int).